Some confusion about $f_{*p}$ when $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ and $p\in \mathfrak{g}^*$
Let $G$ be a Lie group with its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ and $p\in \mathfrak{g}^*$. We know that $(\mathfrak{g}^*)^*\cong \mathfrak{g}$ and for every $p\in \mathfrak{g}^*$, $T_p \mathfrak{g}^*\cong \mathfrak{g}^*$. In fact the map $\mathfrak{g}\to (\mathfrak{g}^*)^*$ defined by $X\to \langle \cdot ,X\rangle$ is an isomorphism where $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle :\mathfrak{g}^*\times \mathfrak{g}\to \mathbb{R}$ is the pairining. Also, the map $\mathfrak{g}^* \to T_p \mathfrak{g}^*$ defined by $X\to D_X|_{p}$ is an isomorphism where $D_X|_p :C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^*)\to \mathbb{R}$ by $D_X|_p(g)=\frac{dg(tX+p)}{dt}|_{t=0}$.
By the fact that $f:\mathfrak{g}^*\to \mathbb{R}$ that sends $p$ to $f(p)$, then $f_{*p}:T_p\mathfrak{g}^*\to T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$ is a linear map. Clearly, $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$. Now since $T_p\mathfrak{g}^*\cong \mathfrak{g}^*$, we can see $f_{*p}$ as linear map from $\mathfrak{g}^*$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (that is my first question). So $f_{*p}\in (\mathfrak{g}^*)^*$. On the other hand, $(\mathfrak{g}^*)^*\cong \mathfrak{g}$, so $f_{*p}\in \mathfrak{g}$ (that is my second question).
My questions: (1) What is the explicit formula of $f_{*p}$ as a map from $\mathfrak{g}^*$ to $\mathbb{R}$? I mean how can we define it explictly so that we can use it directly?
(2) How can we see $f_{*p}$ in $\mathfrak{g}=T_e G$ explicitly as tangent vector at $e$ to use it directly?
